# webkit-transition animation not working on iphone and ipad

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad, webkit-transition

here the my css

```
    .hover-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 4%;
    width: 92%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #72b842;
    visibility: hidden\0/;
    opacity: 0\0/;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(0.8);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(0.8);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(0.8);
    }
```

this transitions a hidden element into view 
the problem is that this is not working on client's iPad and iPhone.
how will you guys approach this problem.
i apologize in advance if i didn't format my question to the standard.